# Process Builder not working through API call

Tags: apex, visualforce, workflow, flow, process-builder

We have a process that works when users create/modify cases from within the UI, however when a case is created by an Apex class and the process gets called b/c of that create, 
the process runs but the criteria do not match.

The process acts to do the following: When a new case is created that is having a particular recordtype, If there is a person account related to the case, then the case assigns ownership to a series of queues based on the Account's region. If there is no account it goes to a general queue.

All of that works when run from the UI just not work through workbench call or apex.

Comment: did you find out why this was... running into the same thing I think